# Extract keys from string of couples using the split function

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, split

I have a column that contains more than one product info in my table.

Data type is string, every product information is separated by semicolons and contains two pieces of information separated by commas.

I need the first string in the couples. Is there a way to handle it with the `SPLIT` function?

For example, values in the column `A,1;B,2;C3;D,4` (Length may be different according to records). Result should be: `A,B,C,D`.

I tried `SPLIT(SPLIT(column,';'),',')`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you working with?

Comment: I use big query

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `SPLIT` returns an array instead of a string, hence you need to unnest your values from your array before reapplying the `SPLIT`. In the end you can use `[offset(0)]` to put your keys into a single column.

If you need them to be aggregated, you can use `ARRAY_AGG` or `STRING_AGG` according to the needs.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SPLIT(<your_field>, ';') AS arr 
    FROM <your_tab>
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SPLIT(couples, ',')[offset(0)]) 
FROM       cte
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(cte.arr) AS couples
```

If you have multiple records which you need to extract keys from, it's better to retain some kind of id (that identifies each row in the input table), bring it through, and use it for the final aggregation (`GROUP BY id`).

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add Group By clause. Now, I tried again and get the result correctly. Thank you very much for your help :)